# Angular unable to access ng-model from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Im new to angular and js
please help me getting json key and bind to ng-model

Following is my code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-model="table.macid"></li>
</ul>
```

and my js is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.table={}

  $http.get("test.json")
    .success(function(response) {

      $scope.names = response
      $scope.table.macid= Object.keys($scope.names.day.weekday.Monday.mac_id)
      console.log($scope.table)
    });
});
```

this is my plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/6CoOAp0X8FZw1JODXSHT?p=preview

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't use `ng-model` on an `<li>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing `ng-model` with `ng-bind`:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-bind="table.macid"></li>
</ul>
```

See **[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JMe9qmCpBYUmHf91XUoe?p=preview)**

In case you need to iterate over the collection, use `ng-repeat`. See zszep answer for that.

Comment: I guess he wants to iterate through the collection. Why else would he use a list item?

Comment: That's indeed a possibility, that's why I added the sentence and referred him to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump it out on your html like this:

```
      <li ng-model="table.macid"></li>{{table.macid}}
```

It should work, it did for me.  You may think you see it because the tag is in an < li > element.  What are you expecting that to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-repeat in the li tag like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2TU2euoeRVPPem1yy4f1?p=preview):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="macid in table.macid">{{macid}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.table={}

      $http.get("test.json")
        .success(function(response) {

          $scope.names = response
          $scope.table.macid= Object.keys($scope.names.day.weekday.Monday.mac_id)

        });console.log($scope.table)
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```